# Optimisation XML handling within vb.net application

Tags: .net, linq, xml, vb.net

I need to optimize this snippet to be faster:

```
Dim lst = (From t In DocElet.ChildNodes Select ID = t.item("ID").outerxml).Distinct().ToList()
       Parallel.For(0, lst.Count, Sub(i)
         Dim P As XmlElement = GetElement(lst(i))
       Dim ls = (From t In DocElet.ChildNodes Where t.item("ID").innerText = P.InnerText Select t)
         Parallel.ForEach(ls, Sub(D)
         Dim verif_date As String = D.Item("DAD").InnerText
        Sej.ID = D.Item("ID").InnerText
         End Sub)
            End Sub)
```

This is the XML structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PatientData>
<Sejour><ID></ID><DAD></DAD></Sejour>
  </PatientData>
```

I'm asking how I can optimize my code because it takes a lot of time (50 sec) in the case where the list contains 20000 elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The indentation makes your snippet quite hard to read - the VB.NET syntax for inline delegates is fairly bulky (at least compared to C#), I'd give it more air; being able to *read* the code is step one.

```
Dim lst = (From t In DocElet.ChildNodes 
           Select ID = t.item("ID").outerxml).Distinct()
                                             .ToList()

Parallel.For(0, lst.Count, 
         Sub(i)
             Dim P As XmlElement = GetElement(lst(i))
             Dim ls = (From t In DocElet.ChildNodes 
                       Where t.item("ID").innerText = P.InnerText 
                       Select t)

             Parallel.ForEach(ls, 
                      Sub(D)
                          Dim verif_date As String = D.Item("DAD").InnerText
                          Sej.ID = D.Item("ID").InnerText
                      End Sub)
         End Sub)
```

Ok. So you're running a `Parallel.For`, and *inside that*, you're running a `Parallel.ForEach`. That's quite a lot of overhead just there, it's likely that you're shooting yourself in the foot here, I'd first remove the inner `Parallel.ForEach`:

```
Parallel.For(0, lst.Count, 
         Sub(i)
             Dim P As XmlElement = GetElement(lst(i))
             Dim ls = (From t In DocElet.ChildNodes 
                       Where t.item("ID").innerText = P.InnerText 
                       Select t)

             For Each foo In ls
                 Dim verif_date As String = D.Item("DAD").InnerText
                 Sej.ID = D.Item("ID").InnerText
             Next
         End Sub)
```

What's the purpose of `verif_date`? If it's not used, remove it:

```
             For Each foo In ls
                 Sej.ID = D.Item("ID").InnerText
             Next
```

Now the outer loop is making yet another selection:

```
             Dim ls = (From t In DocElet.ChildNodes 
                       Where t.item("ID").innerText = P.InnerText 
                       Select t)
```

I'd try to flatten that. I'm not very familiar with the LINQ syntax in VB.NET, but what you want is a `SelectMany`, where you'd select the child nodes where "ID"'s *inner text* matches the element's inner text for the node you're iterating - in other words the `ls` query gets outside the outer loop and into the `lst` query, so you only need a single loop (which can *probably* run in parallel).

If the XML is massive, it *could* be worth trying some PLINQ:

```
Dim lst = (From t In DocElet.ChildNodes 
           Select ID = t.item("ID").outerxml)
          .Distinct()
          .AsParallel()
          .SelectMany(...)
          .ToList()
```

Now you can iterate `lst` with `Parallel.ForEach` (time it with a normal `For Each` first) and do your thing.

As an aside, I have to say your naming is inconsistent and hard to follow: `Sub(i)` looks good (`Sub(index)` would be better), `Sub(D)` doesn't. I realize VB.NET isn't case-sensitive, but if you're going to have a convention to make function parameters `camelCase`, by all means *stick to it*. `lst` would probably be better off as `elements` or whatever makes sense - use real, readable words for your identifiers, not just arbitrary abbreviations.

Comment: is it true : `accessing XML from multiple threads with Parallel.For/Parallel.ForEach is not guaranteed to work correctly as these classes are not thread safe.`

Comment: Awesome, thanks for that comment, that falls under "good to know"! ;)